# Iphone App Xcode (Swift) Trouble

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, xcode4, xcode6

So I started to create my game app and I have run into a problem. I am new to coding and so I am having trouble with the intro to my app. When the app loads it fades in the title and imageview at the top of the screen, so essentially when the screen loads up an imageview and a textbox fade in at the same time 2 seconds after the screen loads. The problem I have is that I also have a "Play Now!" button that fades in after 3 seconds. I need this "Play Now!" button, when clicked, to make that imageview and textbox to fade back out so I can begin the actual game part. And of course the "Play Now!" button will need to fade when clicked as well. How do I connect the button with the two faded in objects?

Comment: This is a very general broad question. Maybe you would like to provide some code you've written.

Comment: Please include [what you have tried](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/) in your post.

Comment: Why all the xcode tags?

Comment: Sorry about all the tags. Here is what I have as far as code goes http://grab.by/GCgO

Comment: I hope that link works for you guys?